# HTML Select using JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript

Please examine the switch statement

Only default option works.

`case x="Fin"` and `case x="Intercom"` are not working. Not sure why. Thanks!

Code:

```
    <p>Niche</p>
        <select name="niche" id="niche" onchange="FCM_niche()">
            <option value="empty" selected="">Select Niche</option>
            <option value="fin">FIN</option>
            <option value="intercom">Intercom</option>
        </select>

    <script type="text/javascript">
                function FCM_niche() {
                    var x = document.getElementById("niche").value;
                   switch (true) {
                        case x="FIN":
                           document.getElementById("FCM_select_niche").innerHTML = "FFFF";
                           break;
                        case x="Intercom":
                           document.getElementById("FCM_select_niche").innerHTML = "IIII";
                           break;
                        default:
                           document.getElementById("FCM_select_niche").innerHTML = "DDDD";
                      }
                };
            </script>
<div id="FCM_select_niche">        
</div>
```

Comment: your switch statement is done wrong.  `switch (true)` negates the whole point of having the switch in the first place.

Comment: @Bango - `switch(true)` is perfectly valid. But in the cases it should be `==` or `===`, not `=`, i.e., it should be a comparison, not an assignment. (`=` isn't a syntax error, but it doesn't do what the OP wants.)

Comment: I'm not debating that it's valid.  It just isnt how switch is meant to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this JS fiddle showing the working version of your code:
https://jsfiddle.net/jspruance/ebjnqt2r/

Just make a few small tweaks to your JS and you should be up and running.

1) Base your switch statement on the 'x' variable: 'switch(x)'

2) Base each case on the selected value (instead of the displayed text):
   ex: case "fin"

```
function FCM_niche() {
    var x = document.getElementById("niche").value;

    switch(x) {
        case "fin":
            document.getElementById("FCM_select_niche").innerHTML = "FFFF";
            break;
        case "intercom":
            document.getElementById("FCM_select_niche").innerHTML = "IIII";
            break;
        default:
            document.getElementById("FCM_select_niche").innerHTML =       "DDDD";
    }
};
```

This should do the trick...good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your switch statement is invalid. Also, you are checking switch case against selected text not on value

```html
    <p>Niche</p>
        <select name="niche" id="niche" onchange="FCM_niche()">
            <option value="empty" selected="">Select Niche</option>
            <option value="fin">FIN</option>
            <option value="intercom">Intercom</option>
        </select>

    <script type="text/javascript">
                function FCM_niche() {
                    var x = document.getElementById("niche").value;
                   switch (x) {
                        case "fin":
                           document.getElementById("FCM_select_niche").innerHTML = "FFFF";
                           break;
                        case "intercom":
                           document.getElementById("FCM_select_niche").innerHTML = "IIII";
                           break;
                        default:
                           document.getElementById("FCM_select_niche").innerHTML = "DDDD";
                      }
                };
            </script>
<div id="FCM_select_niche">        
</div>
```

Comment: *"Your switch statement is invalid."* - What do you mean "invalid"? It is perfectly valid JS syntax that will run without error, it just doesn't do what the OP expects.

Comment: I mean the whole statement, not debating on the syntax @nnnnnn

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = document.getElementById("niche").value;
switch (x) {
  case "FIN":
    document.getElementById("FCM_select_niche").innerHTML = "FFFF";
    break;
  case "Intercom":
    document.getElementById("FCM_select_niche").innerHTML = "IIII";
    break;
  default:
    document.getElementById("FCM_select_niche").innerHTML = "DDDD";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your switch case is wrong

This one is correct

```
function FCM_niche() {
                    var x = document.getElementById("niche").value;
                   switch (x) {
                        case "fin":
                           document.getElementById("FCM_select_niche").innerHTML = "FFFF";
                           break;
                        case "intercom":
                           document.getElementById("FCM_select_niche").innerHTML = "IIII";
                           break;
                        default: document.getElementById("FCM_select_niche").innerHTML = "DDDD";
                           break;
                      }
                };
```

you need to just pass variable with switch(YOUR_VAR)

and just compare it with CASE "YOUR STRING":

Also javascript is case sensitive language , So FIN & fin is not equal value.